# Задать идентификатор элемента управления XAML C#

Tags: c#, xaml

Имеются 9 элементов типа `Button`, требуется работать с ними через цикл `for`,  соответственно для этого нужен идентификатор типа `int`.

Я хочу получить идентификатор элементов именованных `"Knopka1"`... `"Knopka9"` в типе `int`.

Например: как получить идентификатор элемента `Button x:Name="Knopka1"`.

```
<Button x:Name="Knopka1" Content="X" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Также как хотелось бы узнать как в дальнейшем это грамотно использовать.

Comment: `как в дальнейшем это грамотно использовать` - ну наверно не использовать контролы в коде, а использовать наконец привязки и перейти на MVVM?

Answer (score 0):

пишешь в .xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
   <Button x:Name="Knopka1" Content="1" Margin="0,50,0,0"/>
   <Button x:Name="Knopka2" Content="2" Margin="0,100,0,0"/>
   <Button x:Name="Knopka3" Content="3" Margin="0,150,0,0"/>
   <Button x:Name="Knopka4" Content="4" Margin="0,200,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

в .cs

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach (UIElement c in LayoutRoot.Children)
    {
        if (c is Button)
        {
            UIElement button = c;
        }
    }       
}
```

в цикле ты перебираешь все элементы типа Button и можешь считывать все данные, такие как Name, Content и т.д.